# how to calculate the rank of the matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I need to calculate the rank of the $3\times 3$ matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p & p^2 \\
q & 1 & q^2 \\
r^2 & r & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I've already tried many methods,but I can't find an easy way. Here $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all real numbers.

Comment: Do you know anything else about $p$, $q$ and $r$? If not, then you’ll have to examine several cases.

Comment: yeah,i made 4 cases,(pr=1,pq=1(,(pr#1，pq=1),(pr=1,pq#1),(pq#1,pr#1), i think this should be the right answer, but i wonder if there are some easier method..